# Does Homebrew have a command-not-found hook?

Tags: command-line, homebrew

[Arch Linux's pkgfile has a command-not-found hook](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pkgfile#Command_not_found) that you can source from your shell's startup file (*.zshrc*, *.bashrc*, or whatever).  Does Homebrew have anything roughly equivalent to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [homebrew-command-not-found](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-command-not-found). The project tries to reproduce Ubuntu’s `command-not-found` for Homebrew users on OS X.